# Codeigniter , PHP - form validation only letter in other language?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter 3
I use alpha to validate form for only letters

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'FirstName', 'trim|required|alpha',
                array('required' => 'please refill', 'alpha' => 'don't want integer')
            );
```

but the problem is the Thai Language letter is not work T_T(it's work only for English letter). I have already put a meta charset utf-8 on head section, but it's not work too. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the solution you can use the [regex_match](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference) rule and specify allowed characters.
Or you can override the `alpha` rule and implement it with help of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function. Check the [Extending Native Libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries) section of the CodeIgniter docs.

Also you can try to play with locales. The `alpha` rule is implemented using the [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) function. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php), by default, it uses the standard C locale(`[A-Za-z]`). You can try to change locale using the [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function.